# Cannot load packages nor custom app folders in Laravel, dump-autoload doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have a completely default set up of Laravel framework. To include an external library (TwitterOAuth, to be precise), I'm trying to use packages. Besides the official documentation, I followed [this tutorial](http://culttt.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-laravel-4-package/) step-by-step to create my package. However, when I try to put it to action, I see

> Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthServiceProvider' not found

I saw that to solve this problem, I need to do "artisan dump-autoload" in the root of my project folder or in the package folder. I tried both. Whether I execute this command from the root folder or from the package folder, I get "Class not found" exception.

If before doing dump-autoload, I remove the class from "providers" array in /app/config/app.php, and try to launch the command in the root folder, the last thing I see is

> Running for workbench [abraham/twitteroauth]...

And then it gets done without any reports. What is the way to include packages in Laravel?

P.S.: sorry, I'm not including the code, because there's a lot. But basically, it's adjusted code from the tutorial mentioned above.

UPD: I tried to run "composer dump-autoload -o", it finishes successfully, but the problem is still there. Here's the code of composer.json in the root folder:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/models/validators",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

And the one in the package folder:

```
{
    "name": "abraham/twitteroauth",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Abraham Williams",
            "email": "abraham@abrah.am"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Abraham\\TwitterOAuth": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload -o` too. also post the `composer.json`

Comment: where is the package folder? inside `vendor`? are you using git?

Comment: @itachi i'm not using git and i created the package using workbench command, so it's in the workbench folder

Comment: The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#development-workflow) recommends using `php artisan dump-autoload`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @SamSquanch yes, i tried this and just `artisan dump` too